# how can i sort events by id in ascending and descending order in full calendar

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

i need sorting event by id ascending and descending order in full calendar.
it is possible?
if Yes, please give me demo or sample code.

https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/88235/ahNryTJyig06D8f0DCdvkkLXUekz6RLm/

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please see [how to write a good question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and edit your question to provide context and code to show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

you can sort events by giving them time as they all have date.. if time is given they will be sorted according to time but if time is not supplied then it will show events in the same order as they are supplied in the calendar so you can create your own order in array and then pass them to calendar